# i want to delete all files via shell except few as but results in Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
rm -rf  * ! ( "update.sh" | "new_update"  )    #or


rm -rf   ! ( "update.sh" | "new_update"  )     #or


rm -rf   ! ( update.sh | new_update  )         #or
```

I want to delete all files except `update.sh` and `new_update`

I have tired above all lines one by one in shell script but return error

> unexpected token (

and when run directly on terminal some times executes and some times  gives same error as above

Comment: This is not the kind of command you should run until you're 100% it's doing what you want it to do!

Comment: @Chris_Rands could u elaborate little more please

Comment: If you didn't get a shell syntax error, `rm -rf *` is going to delete *everything* in the current directory before `rm` itself looks at your attempt at the exceptions.

Comment: For example, if you thought, "Hey, maybe `rm -rf * '("update.sh" | "new_update" )'` will work", you'd be right: the *shell* will treat it as a perfectly valid command line, the pass every filename in the current directory, along with `("update.sh" | "new_update")`, as arguments to `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to enable extended globbing with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can't have spaces between the parts of the wildcard.

```
rm -rf !(update.sh|new_update)
```

Comment: it works but removes new_update directory  too which i dont want  only update.sh remains

Comment: Before you use `rm`, you should test with `echo`.

Comment: make sure you have no spaces inside the `()`. If you wrote `!(update.sh| new_update)` it will remove `new_update`

Answer (score -2):

You can use `grep -v` to invert match, `-w` for whole words and `-E` fir regex to be able add more files.

```
rm $( printf '%s\n' * | grep -Ewv "update.sh|new_update" )
```

I don't guarantee it to work with filenames containing spaces and other crazy characters.

Safer option that requires gnu extensions is:
([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592301/i-want-to-delete-all-files-via-shell-except-few-as-but-results-in-syntax-error/67641445#comment119561039_67641445) more details)

```
printf '%s\0' * | grep -zEv '^(update.sh|new_update)$' | xargs -0 rm --
```

Ed: as commentator accuse ls and xargs of being 'dangerous' ([here is](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why) I keep it for the record.

```
ls * | grep -Ev "update.sh|new_update" | xargs rm
```

Comment: [Why not parse the output of `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Also, `xargs` is quite buggy (in a buggy-as-designed sense); without use of extensions such as `-0` or `-d`, it breaks filenames with spaces into multiple arguments, strips quotes that are supposed to be parts of the filenames  themselves, etc.

Comment: (As an example of fun corner cases, try running `touch $'file 1\nfile 2'` -- that creates a _single_ file, whose name consists of the string `file 1`, a newline, and then `file 2`; if you used `xargs -d $'\n'` and passed it that name in its literal original form, it would try to delete both `file 1` and `file 2`, but _not_ delete anything with the file's actual name; if you don't use `-d $'\n'`, behavior is even worse).

Comment: As an alternative, consider `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name update.sh -prune -o -name new_update -prune -o -type f -exec rm -- {} +`; that way one avoids all of the bugs involved in using `ls` and `xargs`.

Comment: (Another difference between this code and the OP's spec, including as-edited, is that it deletes anything with `new_update` in the name even if that's not the complete/full name; so this would preserve `new_update.tmp` or `new_update.old`, even though `rm !(update.sh|new_update)` would delete either of those names).

Comment: Is printf better for you? I wouldn't like to loop over with `for` but it's up to OP.

Comment: Somewhat -- it still has bugs, but they're more predictable bugs than the ones `ls` can trigger. `printf '%s\0' * | grep -zEv '^(update.sh|new_update)$' | xargs -0 rm --` would be even better, if GNUisms are acceptable (because the use of `%s\0` instead of `%s\n` neuters problems caused by filenames with newline literals, and `xargs -0` avoids the design bugs I referenced earlier).

Comment: Ok, understood.   Can I quote you in an answer or I leave it as it is?

Comment: Feel free to adopt anything from my comments into the answer. (That's always acceptable here; comments, just like answers, are under a creative commons - attribution license, so both comments and answers can be included in other comments and answers as long as attribution is given).